# IONIC 3 - Cannot send SMSESSION cookie in http rest

Tags: angular, cookies, http-headers, ionic3

I'm creating un APP in IONIC 3. The first action is to making login that return a SMSESSION value. This SMSESSION must be sent in each next http rest call as authentication.

I'm trying to do that but with no success

I'm using this plugin

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

My call is

```
  this.http.get((CURRENT_HOST + endpoint), { headers: this.headers }).subscribe((data) => {},(err) =>{});
```

And header is filled like this

```
this.headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Accept', "application/json")
        .set('Cache-Control', ' "max-age=0" ')
        .set('Connection', ' "keep-alive" ')
        .set('Content-Type', "application/json")
        .set('Cookie', 'SMSESSION=SM_SESSION_RETURNED');
```

But when I debug why java server, in Cookies I found just

- JSESSIONID
- _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID

If I do it in Android all works fine.

Why Could I do to add a custom cookie to my http request on IONIC?

Thanks' in advance

Comment: Are you sure your server allows for custom headers?

Comment: Yes, 'cos when I make request by PostMan, custom cookie is present in HttpServletRequest. If I make request with native Android app too. Just with IONIC 3 this don't happen....

Comment: oh ok. Can you show me your PostMan config?

Comment: It's so simple. I put a rest url toward to my service. I put an header called "Cookie" with value "SMSESSION=******". But I enabled Postman interceptor 'cos header "Cookie" wasn't allowed as header. So I did the same with IONIC 3: I add a interceptor plugin to do that... But no way.... I found this link [link]https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/set-cookie-in-android/83067 [/link]. But did I understand well?? It's impossible to send a cookie??